# How to use Autofac to inject the same instance of DbContext for processing an HTTP request without causing concurrency issues?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, autofac, dbcontext

I'm working on an ASP.net Web API application with Autofac and Entity Framework.

I've been breaking apart different my service classes into smaller classes in order to make my code more testable and to make my code more SOLID.

I'm using Autofac to inject Entity Framework DbContext into my various helper classes.  This becomes problematic because if I use entities queried from DbContext in two different helper classes, I get an error when Entity Framework tries to produce a query.

The error says that Entity Framework cannot produce a query with entities from two different instances of DbContext.

Clearly, the solution is that I need to configure Autofac so that the same instance of DbContext is injected into each of the helper classes, but I'm afraid that if I try to do this, I may get concurrency issues when this application gets deployed to a production environment and many people use it at once.

How do I configure Autofac so that when a request hits my application, my API helper classes all get the same instance of DbContext, but I don't have concurrency issues across multiple requests?

Comment: Been a while, but this is the code we use in our helpers: `var context = (ApplicationDbContext)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));`.

Comment: Missed the "Web API" point... 

From the docs @ https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#no-per-request-filter-dependencies-in-web-api  see "No Per-Request Filter Dependencies in Web API" for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the action filter recommended by the Autofac documentation (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#no-per-request-filter-dependencies-in-web-api) see: "No Per-Request Filter Dependencies in Web API" and manually going to the DependencyResolver for others:

You could have a look at the Medhime DbContextScope unit of work provider. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DbContextScope/)  compiled for both EF6 and EF Core.

The injected dependencies for your classes becomes a DbContextScopeFactory for the top level, and an AmbientDbContextLocator for your services. These don't "break" with Web API's limitation on the request lifetime scope. The ContextScopeFactory would be initialized once and supply the DbContext, while the locators will be fed that single instance.

It may be worth having a look at if managing context references across services and an API action prove clunky.